# Text file reading with dict in python

Tags: file-handling

From bellow text file, read the text file into a python program and group all the words according to their first letter. Represent the groups in form of dictionary. Where the staring alphabet is the "key" and all the words starting with the alphabets are list of "values".

Text file is:

```
Among other public buildings in a certain town, which for many reason it will be prudent to
refine from mentioning, and to which i will assign no fictitious name, there is one anciently
common to most towns, great or small.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stream = open('file name', 'r')
str = ''
current = ' '
while current != '':
    current = stream.read(50)
    str += current
words = str.split(' ')
dict = {}
for w in words:
    if not w[0] in dict:
        dict[w[0]] = [w]
    else:
        dict[w[0]].append(w)
```

The dictionary is *dict*